# Can't view image that downloaded and saved to local files from s3 using aws sdk node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, jpeg

I'm using node js aws-sdk package to download files from s3 storage, and when I download jpeg image and save it as a local file I can't view it. Is it the right way to download jpeg image?

```
  public async downloadFile(fileName: string, targetPath: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const awsObject = await this.s3
        .getObject({
          Bucket: BUCKET,
          Key: fileName,
        })
        .promise();

      fs.writeFileSync(targetPath, awsObject.Body.toString());
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to download file from aws storage with error ${error}`);
    }
  }
```

this is how I call it:

```
await awsSdk.downloadFile('fileInS3.jpeg', `test.jpeg`);
```

When I try to open the saved file I receive an error that says

> The file “test.jpeg” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

### Update

Solved by replacing

```
fs.writeFileSync(targetPath, awsObject.Body.toString());
```

With

```
fs.writeFileSync(targetPath, awsObject.Body as Buffer);
```

Comment: What is the extension of the file?

Comment: Hi Konrad, its Jpeg file.

Comment: And why do you open jpeg in a text editor?

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I use, I don't get any errors. when I debug I can see that 's3.getObject' find the correct file in s3.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem:

```
awsObject.Body.toString()
```

If you're writing an image, converting it to a string is going to break it.

Comment: Thanks David!! That really was the problem, I've updated the post.